# Someone who goes to medical school?

Tags: word-usage

What should I call someone who goes to medical school? A medical student?

Comment: This would be a good question for ELL.

Comment: Does ELL stand for English language learner? I'd like to believe I'm way past that point, but things like this still make me pause every now and then.

Comment: yes. ell.stackexchange.com Though it is a clear straightforward answerable question, and there's the possibility of it having an interesting answer (one never knows), it still seems too local. What about someone who goes to law school? etc, etc.

Comment: I didn't know a Stack Exchange existed for ELL, I may try using that for some of my future questions, thanks!

Comment: Mitch is suggesting that Googling "medical student" + "medical school" would help you answer the question yourself.

Comment: To be fair, we'd call a student at a high school a high school student rather than a high student. Hopefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely, I can think of no better term than *medical student*. *Student doctor* is an alternative I suppose, but less commonly used.

Note that the structure of teaching programs at medical schools, licensing requirements, examinations and so forth, [differ widely throughout the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_school).

A physician who has completed medical school but is not yet fully licensed is referred to, in the United States, as an intern. The nomenclature and training program [vary from country to country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_intern).